# Susy "wide" spans margin

Tags: susy-sass, susy

I'm running into a problem using Susy 2's "wide" option of the span mixin.

I have my gutter-position set to "before".

I have two columns next to each other

```
.container{
   @include container;
}

.branding{
   @include span(3 first);
}

.nav-primary{
   @include span(9 wide);
}

<div class='container'>
   <div class='branding'>...</div>
   <div class='nav-primary'>...</div>
</div>
```

I'm assuming with a .nav-primary's span set to wide that it should not include the left margin, but it does, thus throwing off the layout. I can reset it to zero, but I am wondering if I am doing something wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't assume that just because you want it wide, you also don't want the gutter. We do provide a keyword for easily removing gutters. Try `span(9 wide no-gutters)`.

Comment: Please Hepl me. Need all Example how use - span()

Comment: You should probably start with some of the tutorials by Zell Liew (http://www.zell-weekeat.com/tag/susy/). He's even written a book on it.